# Getting the most common value based on another value?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with country data, a table with COVID measures and a table that links the two, with data that looks a little like this:

```
country:
+----+--------------+
| id | country_name |
+----+--------------+
| 01 | Afghanistan  |
| 02 | Albania      |
| 03 | Algeria      |
|... | ...          |
+----+--------------+

covid_measures:
+------+--------------+---------------+
| m_id | category     | subcategory   |
+------+--------------+---------------+
| 1.1  | Individual   | Hand Hygiene  |
| 1.2  | Individual   | Wear Mask     |
| 1.3  | Individual   | Distancing    |
| 2.1  | Surveillance | Case Detect.  |
| 2.2  | Surveillance | Contact Trace |
| ...  | ...          | ...           |
+------+--------------+---------------+

link_table:
+----+------+-------+
| id | m_id | date  |
+----+------+-------+
| 01 | 1.1  | 21/01 |
| 01 | 3.2  | 24/01 |
| 01 | 8.2  | 25/01 |
| 01 | 3.3  | 28/01 |
| 01 | 1.1  | 28/01 |
|... | ...  | ...   |
+----+------+-------+
```

I want to get the `m_id` and count that was the most used by each country. The output should look something like this:

```
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------+
| country_name | category   | subcategory  | count |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------+
| Afghanistan  | Individual | Wear Mask    | 12    |
| Albania      | Individual | Distancing   | 8     |
| Algeria      | Travel     | Stay at home | 10    |
| ...          | ...        | ...          | ...   |
+--------------+------------+--------------+-------+
```

What I have so far counts the occurrence of each measure by country, but I am not sure how to get the most common from those by country.

```
SELECT country_name, category, subcategory, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM link_table AS l
JOIN country AS c ON l.id = c.id
JOIN coid_measure AS cm ON cm.m_id = l.m_id
GROUP BY country_name, category, subcategory
ORDER BY country_name, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This gives this:

```
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------+
| country_name | category     | subcategory   | count |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------+
| Afghanistan  | Individual   | Wear Mask     | 12    |
| Afghanistan  | Individual   | Distancing    | 10    |
| Afghanistan  | Travel       | Close Border  | 9     |
| Afghanistan  | Surveillance | Contact Trace | 8     |
| ...          | ...          | ...           | ...   |
+--------------+--------------+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: I think you're confusing data display (e.g. legal numbering) with data storage and retrieval

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to use window functions.  This requires a subquery:

```
SELECT ccs.*
FROM (SELECT c.country_name, cm.category, cm.subcategory, COUNT(*) AS count,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.country_name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM link_table l JOIN
           country c
           ON l.id = c.id JOIN
           covid_measure cm
           ON cm.m_id = l.m_id
      GROUP BY country_name, category, subcategory
    ) ccs
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY country_name, COUNT(*) DESC;
```